# Typescript add typing on Fn's parametrs with destructuring+rest

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

#### Problems

Hi try to learn some typing in typescript but faced some issue on trying to add the typing in Typescript:

I am not sure how to convert this into strongly-typed in Typescript.

```
const omit = (prop: P, { [prop]: _, ...rest}) => rest;
```

- so the problem is how to add typing for the destructured object inside second parameter

#### What I tried

This is what I think it should look like but not working:

```
const omit = <P = string, R>(prop: P, { [prop]: _, ...rest } : {[prop: string], rest: R }): R => rest;

const omit = <P = string, O, R = Omit<O,P>>(prop: P, { [prop]: _, ...rest } : {[prop: string]: O[P], rest: R }): R => rest;

const omit = <P = string, R>(prop: P, { [prop]: _, ...rest } : {[prop]: P, rest: R }): R => rest;
```

Comment: You have severe syntax errors that make it difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish. I recommend you **1)** provide a plain JS example of what you are attempting to model in TypeScript, **2)** take a TypeScript tutorial.

Comment: Not sure what is severe about the example above but I have red the doc. Sorry to confused you I already stated that the code block below that I was showing is what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually fairly straightforward to write. You're on the right track in terms of using generics but your trying to express the type of the second parameter in terms of how it will be broken up to compute the function's result which isn't the way to go here.

Instead, allow the second parameter to take any type, by declaring an unconstrained generic, and specify the type of the first parameter as being constrained to be any of the property the keys of whatever type the generic is instantiated with, that is whatever the type of the second parameter is.

```
const omit = <O, P extends keyof O>(prop: P, { [prop]: _, ...rest }: O): Omit<O, P> => rest;
const o = { a : 1, b: 2 };
const r = omit('a', o);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCC2BLWBeGAeA8gGhgBRgFMAPKQsAEwhgGtCBPEAMxkwD4AKABwCcQuAXPlwBvGAG1e-ALpCA+rgB0ynoWgwAvkMwBKbUihZceNjBSnV0ANwBYAFChIsEGZhiAhjCEBGXACMhACZNWwdwdR5XBGQOAHJ3WNwQHSsgA)

Note that the return type of the function will be properly inferred as `Omit<O, P>` and need not be specified.

```
const omit = <O, P extends keyof O>(prop: P, { [prop]: _, ...rest }: O) => rest;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I was overcomplicating things and don't think typescript are able to represent this complex form.
This should be the simple way to do it ! 